# Drupal commerce save personnal field

Tags: drupal, field, commerce

I'm new to Drupal Commerce ...

I added two fields in the order table :
field_date_de_livraison (text) and field_info_comp_cmde (long text).

In a personalized pane , I try to save the entered values ​​with this code :

function pane_date_livraison_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

```
if (!empty($form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']])) {
    $Date_saisie = $form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']];    
    if (!empty($Date_saisie['date_livraison'])) {
        $Date_sauvegarde = new DateTime($Date_saisie['date_livraison']);            
        $Date_sauvegarde = $Date_sauvegarde->format('d/m/Y');                        
        $order->field_date_de_livraison = $Date_sauvegarde;
    }
    if (!empty($Date_saisie['info_comp'])) {
        $order->field_info_comp_cmde = $Date_saisie['info_comp'];
    }              
  }
 dpm($order, "RETURN_SUBMIT", $type = 'status');
```

}

With dpm , I see the values ​​assigned to variables , but then they are not saved to the table?

Thank's for your answers !

Comment: Hello, finally , I succeeded with this method :

Comment: $order = commerce_order_load($form_state['order']->order_id);        
        $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
        $order_wrapper->field_order_info_complementaires->set($valeurs_saisie['info_complementaires']);
        commerce_order_save($order);